# Using dispatcher to invoke on another thread - Config/Settings is not threadsafe in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: wpf, multithreading, .net-core, configuration, dispatcher

### Issue:

I am trying to update the GUI from a second thread.
Unfortunately the label stays the same. At first I thought there is an issue with the dispatcher but it works fine. It appears that the configuration is not threadsafe!

### Code to reproduce:

I have a Settings File which is mainly used to keep variables persistent during application relaunches:
[image]

this is the Update code:

```
// get the amount of tickets created for me last week
int amountOftickets = JiraInterface.DayStatisticsGenerator.GetLastWeeksTicketAmount();
config.Default.Lastweekstickets = amountOftickets; // int == 12;
// Update GUI on GUI thread
mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    mainWindow.SetIconsAccordingtoConfig();
    mainWindow.NumberTicketsCreated.Content = config.Default.Lastweekstickets.ToString(); // int == 0!!
});
```

Does anyone have an Idea on how to shove the running configuration  from the thread who updated it to the Gui thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick look in the documentation, it seems that you have 2 options:

- You can either use the Dispatcher.Invoke to set your config.Default
  on GUI thread.
- It seems that .NET Core and .NET Framework support synchronized SettingsBase which is what the Configs are ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingsbase.synchronized?view=netcore-3.0 )

EDIT 1:
Looking into the C# Properties more, it seems that if you look in your config file in Visual Studio under:

- Properties -> Config.settings -> Config.Designer.cs

During the class initialization it seems that .NET Framework, already uses Synhronized property which should make the config thread safe

`private static Config defaultInstance = ((Config)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Config())));`

[image: Example of our config]

It could be that when you created this file, Synchronized wasn't used, so your config file isn't thread safe, especially if it was created in code and not designer/properties

From Microsoft Docs on SettingsBase Synchronized:

> The indexer will get and set property data in a thread-safe manner if the IsSynchronized property is set to true. A SettingsBase instance by default is not thread-safe. However, you can call Synchronized passing in a SettingsBase instance to make the SettingsBase indexer operate in a thread-safe manner.